# String capitalize with python

Tags: python, string

Now I Am doing very small question at [HackRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/capitalize) about string manipulations it is very easy one just like homework dump . The question is turn a given string to capitalize they mentioned their question just like below

You are given a string . Your task is to capitalize each word of S.

Input Format

A single line of input containing the string, S.

Constraints

```
0< len(s) <1000
```

The string consists of alphanumeric characters and spaces.
Output Format

Sample Input

```
hello world
```

Sample Output

```
Hello World
```

I have done here I wrote a two line script from python and I submitted it but
 they said it is a wrong answer but I can't understand why is that my code is follow

```
l=list(map(str.capitalize,input().strip(' ').split()))
print(' '.join(l))
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code
**(it fails on test cases 1 / 3 / 4 / 5 with Python 3, so )**
?

Comment: Please peoples **READ THE QUESTION !** The op is not asking for "how to" nor "a better way", he's asking **why** his code fails the tests on HackRank !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specifiy the separator to `str.split()`, "any whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed from the result." Note that here "whitespace" includes tabs, newlines etc.

The problem is not clearly specified (there's no definition of what "word" means) and we don't know what they use for test cases, but I assume they have a couple string with newlines or such. Anyway: explicitely specifying `" "` as the separator makes the tests pass:

```
# Python 2
s = raw_input()
print " ".join(x.capitalize() for x in s.strip().split(" "))

# Python 3
s = input()
print(" ".join(x.capitalize() for x in s.strip().split(" ")))
```

Comment: Thank you lot sir .finally my code also worked .Thank you sir!!  `l=list(map(str.capitalize,input().strip(' ').split(' ')))

print(' '.join(l))`

Comment: Now that you know why your code failed, you may want to read up Patrick Haugh's answer... which while not answering your question is still the pythonic way to capitalize all words in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.title`

```
>>>'aba aba'.title()
'Aba Aba'
```

Comment: How does that answer the question ?

Comment: Any one have any idea why does my code can't submit in hackrank

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I know what's a XY problem is thanks, but that seems irrelevant here - just as your answer is actually. The OP don't ask for a better solution, he asks for why his code is considered wrong by HackRanck.

Answer (score -1):

I presume the error is on `input()`. If HackRank is using python 2.7, this will try to evaluate the input, rather than returning a string. Thus, an input `hello world` will try to evaluate this string, which is nonsense. If you try `raw_input()` in stead, this should fix this problem.

Comment: I just tried the problem on HackRank and you do have the choice of Python 2 or Python 3. I assume the OP submitted this as Python 2, indeed.

Comment: no i used python 3 .I double checked it on HackRank

Comment: Ok it fails on test cases 1 / 3 / 4 / 5 with Python 3, so `input()` is not the culprit.

Comment: @RavinduShantha please edit your post to add these infos.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay i will